# PHP Simple object oriented application

Tags: php, class, oop, instance-variables

I am getting undefined variable for periods and subPeriods on the last line of this program. not sure what the problem is. Could it be my instances?

This is my first proper attempt at oop in PHP so i am sure i am doing something wrong.

```
$global_periods = 5;
$global_subperiods = 2;

$questionslist = array("q_1_1", "q_1_2", "q_2_1", "q_2_2", "q_3_1", "q_4_1", "q_5_1");

class User {
    public $userId;
    public $periods = array();

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->userId = $number;
    }

    public function addPeriod($pno)
    {
        $periods[] = new Period($pno);
    }
}

class Period {
    public $periodNo;
    public $subPeriods = array();

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->periodNo = $number;
    }

    public function addSubPeriod($spno)
    {
        $subPeriods[] = new SubPeriod($spno);
    }
}

class SubPeriod {
    public $SubPeriodNo;
    public $answers = array();

    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->SubPeriodNo = $number;
    }

    public function addAnswer($answer)
    {
        $answers[] = new Answer($answer);
    }
}

class Question {
    public $answer;

    public function __construct($ans)
    {
        $this->answer = $ans;
    }

    public function getAnswer()
    {
        echo $answer;   
    }
}        

$userlist = array();

$sql = 'SELECT user_ref FROM _survey_1_as GROUP BY user_ref ORDER BY user_ref ASC';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $userlist[] = new User($row['user_ref']);
}

for ($i = 0; $i >= count($userlist); $i++)
{
    for ($x = 1; $x > $global_periods; $x++)
    {
        $userlist[i]->addPeriod($x);

        for ($y = 1; $y > $global_subperiods; $y++)
        {
            $userlist[i]->$periods[x]->addSubPeriod($y);

            foreach($questionslist as $aquestion)
            {
                $sql = 'SELECT ' . $questionNumber . ' FROM _survey_1_as WHERE user_ref = ' .
                     $i . ' AND answer_sub_period = ' . $y . ' AND answer_period = ' . $x .''; 

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $userlist[i]->$periods[x]->$subPeriods[y]->addAnswer($row[$questionNumber]);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

$userlist[3]->$periods[2]->$subPeriods[2]->getAnswer();
```

Comment: takeout all $ after $userlist[3]->

Comment: You have to dimiss the `$` sign for fields in objects.
`$userlist[3]->periods[2]->subPeriods[2]->getAnswer();`

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\data_portal\maths.php on line 125

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\data_portal\maths.php on line 125

Fatal error: Call to a member function getAnswer() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\data_portal\maths.php on line 125

Line 125 is the last line. got those errors are making your changes.

Comment: You are inserting a `Period` with `$x=1` into `periods[0]`. When you try to access that `Period` by using `$x` as index, you try to get the wrong item. Obviously, an undefined one. Same for `subPeriods`

Comment: There are 5 periods and 2 sub periods so i changed them to this...
for ($y = 0; $y > 1; $y++)   and   for ($x = 0; $x > 5; $x++)   but still getting errors I think its with the answers now

Comment: shouldn't it bei `for($y = 0; $y < $global_subperiods; $y++)` etc.? Not `>` but `<`. With the `>` condition, the loops aren't executed properly because the initial value doesn't match the condition.

Comment: changed it to that and still getting those new errors. So the array is out of bounds? is that what that means?

Comment: Yep. I just realised, when you add 2 periods, the highest index in the `periods` array is, of course, 1. So you got a hardcoded wrong index. But this isn't related to your original question anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the $ signs behind the $userlist, you only need to define the first variable. You can't use dollar signs like this, this way, it will try get the value of the word after the $ sign and call that, but that variable doesn't exist.